# Can you bring back to life a decomposed corpse using Restore Corpse?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, resurrection

Let's say you have an old corpse (which could be a skeleton) that didn't die from old age, and that your mage casts a [Restore Corpse](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spells/restoreCorpse.html#restore-corpse), whose effect is:

> You grow flesh on a decomposed or skeletonized corpse of a Medium or
>   smaller creature, providing it with sufficient flesh that it can be
>   animated as a zombie rather than a skeleton. The corpse looks as it
>   did when the creature died. The new flesh is somewhat rotted and not
>   fit for eating.

Can this corpse be brought back to life, despite having been dead for a bit of time and/or having been dramatically altered (decomposed, eaten, etc.)?

Comment: RE: "[A]nd not fit for eating." I think I speak for everyone when I say, "Darn." Gags aside, since higher-level effects *create bodies* for souls to inhabit or don't need a complete corpse, it might be a good idea to specify the effect that you're planning to use to bring back the dead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, mostly

It really depends on which effect is being used to bring her back to life.

- [Raise Dead](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/raiseDead.html#raise-dead) probably won't work, as the target cannot be dead for longer than *caster level* days;
- [Reincarnate](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/reincarnate.html#reincarnate) also won't work, as it has a limit of *one week*;
- [Resurrection](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/resurrection.html#resurrection) should work, as the limit is *10 years* per *caster level*, meaning that a 13th level cleric can bring back someone who has been dead for 130 years (!);
- Similarly, [True Resurrection](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/trueResurrection.html#true-resurrection) should also work (10 years per *caster level* as well), the only difference is that unlike the (untrue) resurrection effect, you don't need any remains or body part of the deceased for the spell to work.

Keep in mind that for both resurrection spells, it says:

> The condition of the remains is not a factor.

So whether or not you use *Restore Corpse* first is irrelevant for those two spells. When bringing back someone that died within a few days using *Raise Dead*, however, it is a good idea to either preserve the body using [Gentle Repose](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/gentleRepose.html#gentle-repose) or other means of preservation.

[Restore Corpse](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spells/restoreCorpse.html#restore-corpse), however, does not mention anything about making the corpse fit for Raise Dead again, so it has no special effect on that spell.